# Cannot use custom view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

For my SwiftUI application, I've created a simple `Title` view, that has a set font size and text color. `Title` is declared as follows:

```
struct Title: View {
    var string: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(string)
            .font(.system(size: 32))
            .color(Color.black)
    }
}
```

I have the following text objects in my content view's body right now:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Welcome")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .color(Color.black)
        Text("to SwiftUI")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .color(Color.secondary)
    }
}
```

So now, I want to replace these two `Text`s with my `Title`s:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Title("Welcome")
        Title("to SwiftUI")
    }
}
```

After replacing the views, I'm getting some seemingly unrelated error messages from Xcode, that stop the application from compiling:

> Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'
>
> '(LocalizedStringKey) -> Text' is not convertible to '(LocalizedStringKey, String?, Bundle?, StaticString?) -> Text'
>
> 'Font' is not convertible to 'Font?'

...and more. Reverting back to `Text` instead of `Title` "fixes" the issues.

What's interesting is that I also have a custom `PrimaryButton` view that I was able to add without any issues:

```
struct PrimaryButton: View {
    var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { print("tapped") }) {
            Text(title)
                .font(Font.primaryButton)
                .offset(y: 1)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .padding(.vertical, 14)
        }
    }
}
```

...and then using it:

```
PrimaryButton(title: "Let's go")
```

---

#### Question

Is this simply a beta-issue, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `string:` to your `Title()` initializer:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Title(string: "Welcome")
        Title(string: "to SwiftUI")
    }
}
```

Compiler errors are currently misleading and not located near where the real issue is.

Comment: Ahh I did not spot that, thanks! For leaving it out, do I *have to* write a custom initializer?

Comment: You need to provide values for all struct values when creating one, but you don't have to explicitly write a custom initializer. But as of Swift 5.1 (I believe), you only have to provide values for those members which are not initialized with default values.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `string:` param in the initializer.
Please find the updated code below:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Title(string: "Welcome")
        Title(string: "to SwiftUI")
    }
}
```

FYI:
**I have created one sample application**

```
// MARK - CustomView

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            CustomView(aString: "First String")
            CustomView(aString: "Second String")
        }
    }
}

// MARK - CustomView

struct CustomView : View {
    var aString: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(aString)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with `TextField` instead of `Text` Views? How do I get the value of the `@State` var for the `TextField` from the View that is using it?

Comment: Can you share the link to your sample application

Answer (score 0):

Today, 01oct2019, Swift prompted me to replace `string:`  with. `verbatim:` .

`Text(verbatim: "Pressure")` works today
`Text(string: "Pressure")` did work yesterday but not today.
hth